# Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

> Warning: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a
>   value of `string` type.
>       in span (at App.js:62)
>       in div (at App.js:61)
>       in form (at App.js:60)
>       in div (at App.js:58)
>       in div (at App.js:46)
>       in App (at index.js:8)

I am getting this error in App.js when i try to get the onclick event for button..

```
<h2>Login From Here..!</h2>

                <button onClick={document.getElementById('id01')}>Login</button>
```

Can anyone explain me how to get rid from this error?

Comment: `document.getElementById('id01')` is **not** a function, `() => document.getElementById('id01')` **is**. In the first case you are just calling the function as the object gets constructed, the later case passed a function to be called later. I am presuming you should tag this React?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a function:

```
document.getElementById('id01')
```

It's a *function call*, so whatever is returned from this function is a value, and that value gets converted to a String and then passed to your `onClick`. Instead, use something like this:

```
event => document.getElementById('id01')
```

or this more long-form version:

```
function( event ){

    return document.getElementById('id01');

}
```

It's still useless, as it will return the element to... nowhere and that's it, but at least it gets rid of your `Error`.